# Need help deriving the Schwartz inequality.

Tags: calculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am trying to prove the Schwartz Inequality (through an exercise) in the form of
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i \le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}^2}
\tag{1}
$$
through a method of knowing that there is no $\lambda$ for $x_1 =\lambda y_1$ & $x_2 =\lambda y_2$  through which we can easily make out that
$$
 0 < \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\lambda y_i -x)^2
\tag{2}
$$
**or**
$$
0< \lambda^2 (\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2) - 2\lambda (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i) + (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2)
\tag{3}
$$
No problem there. For the next couple of steps, I am going to denote $(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2)$ by $a$, $(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i)$ by $b$ and $(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2)$ by $c$ (to reduce time writing this),
for example, $(3)$ is written as
$$
0 < \lambda ^2(a)-2\lambda(b) +c
\tag{4}
$$
which we can proceed to make into
$$
0<\lambda ^2-2\lambda(ba^{-1})+ca^{-1}
\tag{5}
$$
Now, since from $(3)$, we can see that $0=\lambda ^2(a)-2\lambda(b)+c$ has no solution for $\lambda$ as I already stated that there is no $\lambda$ for $x_1 =\lambda y_1$ & $x_2 =\lambda y_2$ , so we can say that for $(5)$,

$$
 (ba^{-1})^2-4(ca^{-1}) < 0
\tag{6}
$$
$(6)$ is derived from $b^2-4c<0$ (**here is where I made my mistake, I don't know why I didn't use** $b^2-4ac$ **sorry for this stupid mistake, from here I go on to try to make** $a = 1$) for cases where we don't have a solution. Bringing back the summations, we get
$$
(-2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2)^{-1})^2-4(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2)^{-1} < 0
\tag{7}
$$
which is as far as I got. I tried doing
$$
4(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i)^2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2)-4(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2)^{-1} < 0
\tag{8} 
$$
but I don't know how to get to $(1)$. So, did I do something wrong? Can someone elaborate on what I am meant to do? I am so sorry for the stupid question, I am really tired and (even though that's not an excuse,) I feel like I made a mistake somewhere and I really want to know the answer by the end of today. Thank you so much.

- **I am sorry if I am making any stupid mistakes, I am tired but I can't sleep without knowing how to do this.**

Comment: I wasn't sure about the tags, if they are misleading or lacking, please feel free to change them. I didn't really know if this fit into "Calculus", sorry about that.

Comment: I edited wording, nothing big.

Comment: Line $(8)$ should be $4b^2a^{\color{red}{-2}}-4ca^{-1}< 0$, i.e. $a^{-2}(4b^2-4ac)<0$.

Comment: Note that it is “Schwarz”, not “Schwartz”, named after [Karl Hermann Amandus Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Schwarz).

Comment: @peterwhy You're right, but regardless, I messed up this whole proof, I wouldn't really know where to go from $(8)$, even with your correction, maybe there someway, but I am not going to bother then, it would've been much easier if I just used $b^2-4ac < 0$ (something noted in the answer below) instead of trying to make $a=1$, this whole question was a mess, regardless, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Sdavid552 From the corrected $(8)$ and multiply both sides by $\frac{a^2}{4}$, you get $b^2-ac < 0$. Sure it's a longer route with some extra division and multiplication of $a^2$, but it's too harsh to say everything was a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go back to
$0 < \lambda ^2(a)-2\lambda(b) +c$.

Using the original quadratic formula,
the discriminant is
$d = (2b)^2-4ac
=4(b^2-ac)
$.

For the quadratic
to have no real roots,
$d < 0$
so
$b^2-ac < 0$
so
$b^2 < ac$.

Comment: Now that I am in a much better mood, I am going to comment for the last time. Thank you very much for the answer, originally I placed "<" the wrong way around; I already fixed it. What I was saying is that $0=\lambda ^2(a)−2\lambda (b)+c$ had no solution hence $b^2−ac$ had to be $<0$. I am sorry for wasting your time but I thank you for taking your time to answer me. I ended up getting my answer by taking the much simpler route mentioned in the comments. P.S. I wasn't happy with my comment I made yesterday in a rush.